# JSON API with Flutter is not fetching data

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem fetching data from a json api.
I have this structure:

```
{
    "team": {
        "team_name": "Team Name",
        "team_quantity": 10,
        "team_victory": 2,
    }
}
```

and I'm trying to fetch data with Flutter:

```
class Team{
 final String name;
 final int quantity;
 final int victory;

  Team({this.name, this.quantity, this.victory});

  factory Team.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return Team(
      name: json['team_name'] as String,
      quantity: json['team_quantity'] as int,
      victory: json['team_victory'] as int,
    );
  }
}

Future<List<Team>> fetchTeam(http.Client client) async {
  final response =
      await http.get('url');
  return compute(parseTeam, response.body);
}

List<Team> parseTeam(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  return parsed.map<Team>((json) => Team.fromJson(json)).toList();
}
```

I get this error:

```
I/flutter (25834): Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'cast' with matching arguments.
I/flutter (25834): Receiver: _LinkedHashMap len:1
I/flutter (25834): Tried calling: cast<Map<String, dynamic>>()
I/flutter (25834): Found: cast<RK, RV>() => Map<RK, RV>
```

Could you explain the error(s) to me? Thanks so much!

Maybe my problem could be the "team" in the api? I will try fetching data with the same structure in Flutter:

```
{
    "team": {
        "team_name": "Team Name",
        "team_quantity": 10,
        "team_victory": 2,
    }
}

or

{
   "team_name": "Team Name",
   "team_quantity": 10,
   "team_victory": 2,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing

```
final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
```

with

```
final Map<String, dynamic> parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody);
```

Comment: i already seen it, but doesn't work for me... the problem could be the "team:{...}" ? I will edit the question with an exmple (thanks for the reply!)

Comment: Is it throwing the same error when you make the change ?

Comment: yes, i edited the main post if you want help me... I don't understand how can i modify my structure

Comment: I tested my solution with your code and json, and it solves the error. Maybe you have the same error somewhere else ? Also, is your Flutter up-to-date ? If not, run `flutter upgrade`.

Comment: i don't know how to return with the new parsed. How can i change the return: `return parsed.map<Team>((json) => Team.fromJson(json)).toList();`

Comment: I think you have to make it `parsed.values.map()`. A more readable syntax is `var list = <Team>[for(var value in parsed.values) Team.fromJson(value)];`

Comment: It is perfect, thanks so much... i can't vote your reply because i don't have reputation to do it and i am new... but thanks so much!!!

Comment: You can't select a correct answer on your own question ? Curious. It's ok though, glad I could help :)

Comment: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." Yes i can but it is not visible, i did it anyway!! :) Oh i can't vote, but i can accept it, okok

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine just use this

```
{
   "team_name": "Team Name",
   "team_quantity": 10,
   "team_victory": 2,
}
```

also make sure you have these imports

```
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
```

if you want use with Teams then wrap teams with another class like league

```
 class League {
 List<Team> teams;
League({this.teams});
factory League.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json,) {
    if (json["team"] != null) {
      var teams1= json["team"] as List;
      List<Team> _teams=
      teams1.map((list) => Team.fromJson(list)).toList();
      return League(
        teams: _teams,
      );
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

and this is how you fetch data

```
Future<League> getLeague() async {
  final response = await http.Client().get('$url');
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return League.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i can't use this, i can use only the first with "team", how can i modify the code to fetch data in this case

Comment: Don't work for me... where you use the "teams1" variable? Did you test it? Thanks again for the help

Comment: sorry about that i editted again. this must work imo.

Comment: oh ok perfect, i get always the same error... this part is correct? Future<List<League>> fetchLeague(http.Client client) async {
  final response =
      await http.get('url');
  return compute(parseLeague, response.body);
}

List<League> parseLeague(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  return parsed.map<League>((json) => League.fromJson(json)).toList();
}